# investpy RuntimeError: ERR#0019: fund not found, check if it is correct

Tags: python

I would like to load stock quotes automatically from the Internet. Preferably by entering the ISIN or WKN. During the search I came across investpy. Investpy obtains data from https://www.investing.com/

```
import investpy
df = investpy.funds.get_fund_historical_data('AT0000705678', 'austria', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2021', as_json = False, order = 'ascending', interval = 'Daily')
```

Leads to an error:

```
RuntimeError: ERR#0019: fund at0000705678 not found, check if it is correct.
```

But on the website the ISIN is found: https://www.investing.com/funds/at0000705678

Answer (score 1):

The investpy API doesn't support searching for ISINs. See here:
https://investpy.readthedocs.io/_api/funds.html#investpy.funds.get_fund_historical_data

In general, there are many assets that are listed on investing.com but not (yet) accessible via investpy.

I use this approach, using [package tessa](https://github.com/ymyke/tessa):

```py
pip install tessa
from tessa import search, price_history
r = search('Erste Wwf Stock Environment Eur R01 T')
prices, currency = price_history(r[0], 'searchobj')
prices, currency = price_history(r['investing_searchobj_perfect'][0], 'searchobj')
```